# Select random element from SKScene after shake gesture

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a very basic app, that displays at random positions on the screen circles (that I named bubbles) and those bubbles moves when I rotate my device.

I'm trying to implement a method which is triggered when I shake the device, and that makes every bubbles disappears from the scene and choose a random bubble and place it at the center of the screen (a kind of lottery of bubbles basically).
That same bubble should not move until I touch it.When I do touch it, everything goes back to normal with all of my bubbles on my screen moving with my device's rotation.

My question : how I can make disappear every node and choose a random node to display it and center it on the screen.

This is my code :

```
import CoreMotion
import SpriteKit


class Bubble: SKShapeNode{}
class BName: SKLabelNode {}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var motionManager: CMMotionManager?
    let bubbles = ["bubble1", "bubble2", "bubble3"]

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        for bubble in bubbles {
            let ball = Bubble(circleOfRadius: 50)
            let ball_name = SKLabelNode(text: bubble)
            ball_name.position = CGPoint(x: ball.frame.midX, y: ball.frame.midY)
            ball.position = CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.width)))) , y: (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.height)))))
            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
            ball.fillColor = UIColor.blue
            ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
            ball.physicsBody?.mass = 1
            ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            ball.addChild(ball_name)
            addChild(ball)
        }

         
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        
        motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        motionManager?.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        
    }
    
    
   
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        
        if let accelerometerData = motionManager?.accelerometerData {
            physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.y * -66, dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 66)
        }
    }
    
    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            // call a function that take a random bubble and
            // display it at the center of the screen, while the
            // other ones disappears until I touch the bubble
            // and then all of the others re-appears including that random one
            // with every bubbles floating on the screen ie. what we had before
            // the shake
        }
    }

}
```

I think I need to use SKAction but I do not know how to choose the random node, and make all of the other bubbles disappears.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to enumerate through all of the nodes.

If you create a bubble container node, you can assign all of your bubbles to that.

Then randomly select a bubble from its children, and follow it weith removeAllChildren.

```
import CoreMotion
import SpriteKit


class Bubble: SKShapeNode{}
class BName: SKLabelNode {}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var motionManager: CMMotionManager?
    let bubbles = ["bubble1", "bubble2", "bubble3"]
    let bubbleContainer = SKNode()
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        addChild(bubbleContainer)
        for bubble in bubbles {
            let ball = Bubble(circleOfRadius: 50)
            let ball_name = SKLabelNode(text: bubble)
            ball_name.position = CGPoint(x: ball.frame.midX, y: ball.frame.midY)
            ball.position = CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.width)))) , y: (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.height)))))
            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
            ball.fillColor = UIColor.blue
            ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
            ball.physicsBody?.mass = 1
            ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            ball.addChild(ball_name)
            bubbleContainer.addChild(ball)
        }

         
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        
        motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        motionManager?.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        
    }
    
    
   
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        
        if let accelerometerData = motionManager?.accelerometerData {
            physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.y * -66, dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 66)
        }
    }
    
    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            // call a function that take a random bubble and
            // display it at the center of the screen, while the
            // other ones disappears until I touch the bubble
            // and then all of the others re-appears including that random one
            // with every bubbles floating on the screen ie. what we had before
            // the shake
        }
    }

    func popBubbles(){
        let random = *** // use random method of your choice, limit it to children count
        let selectedBubble =  bubbleContainer.children[random]
        bubbleContainer.removeAllChildren()
        bubbleContainer.addChild(selectedBubgle)
        //perform actons on selectedBubble here
        ***
        //add remaining bubbles here
        ***
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483024-enumeratechildnodeswithname?language=objc) to iterate over all bubbles. Add the bubbles to an array, get the number of bubbles, pick one at random and then remove every other bubble (using removeFromParent).

Position the one remaining bubble in the centre of the screen.